# Android: FTP-Connection does not work and can't show image via universal image loader

Tags: android, ftp

When I connect to my online ftp server (ftp.spicy-software.com) it does not work, no errors or crashes. just a blank layout. But when I connect to my LOCAL ftp server it works and the pictures will be shown. why??

I am connecting to my local ftp server (Local-IP: 192.168.99.105) that works great and the pictures will be shown in the gridview:

[image]

```
    new FtpTask().execute();

    private class FtpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, FTPClient> {
     protected FTPClient doInBackground(Void... args) {
         //connectFTP("192.168.99.105", "Username", "Password", 21);
         connectFTP("ftp.spicy-software.com", "USername1", "Passweord", 21);
        return null;

     }

     protected void onPostExecute(FTPClient result) {
         Log.v("FTPTask","FTP connection complete");
     }
    }
```

connectFTP() Function:

```
    public void connectFTP(String host, String username, String password, int port){

    try {
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.connect(host, port);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.login(username, password);
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("GetThePicture/pictures/");
        Log.v("FTP STATUS: ",ftpClient.getStatus());


        FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles();

        for (FTPFile file : files) {
            Log.v("File: ", "http://spicy-software.com/GetThePicture/pictures/"+file.getName());
            imageUrls.add("http://www.spicy-software.com/GetThePicture/pictures/"+file.getName());
            imageNames.add(file.getName());
        }

        Log.v("FILE_1: ", imageUrls.get(1));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("Error", ""+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**But when I try to connect to the ftp.spicy-software.com online ftp server it does not work:**

LogCat:

```
05-01 15:31:50.280: D/AbsListView(2136): Get MotionRecognitionManager

05-01 15:31:50.345: D/libEGL(2136): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
05-01 15:31:50.350: D/libEGL(2136): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
05-01 15:31:50.350: D/libEGL(2136): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
05-01 15:31:50.355: D/(2136): Device driver API match
05-01 15:31:50.355: D/(2136): Device driver API version: 10
05-01 15:31:50.355: D/(2136): User space API version: 10 
05-01 15:31:50.355: D/(2136): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
05-01 15:31:50.390: D/OpenGLRenderer(2136): Enabling debug mode 0
05-01 15:31:53.605: V/FTP STATUS:(2136): 211-Status of 'ftp.easyname.eu'

05-01 15:31:53.605: V/FTP STATUS:(2136): 211-Connected from 109.164.221.167 (109.164.221.167)

05-01 15:31:53.605: V/FTP STATUS:(2136): 211-Logged in as 35221ftp1

05-01 15:31:53.605: V/FTP STATUS:(2136): 211-TYPE: BINARY, STRUcture: File, Mode: Stream

05-01 15:31:53.605: V/FTP STATUS:(2136): 211-No data connection

05-01 15:31:53.605: V/FTP STATUS:(2136): 211 End of status

05-01 15:31:53.910: W/dalvikvm(2136): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'UNIX Type: L8'
05-01 15:31:55.285: D/dalvikvm(2136): GC_CONCURRENT freed 167K, 10% free 12399K/13703K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 24ms
05-01 15:31:55.775: V/File:(2136): http://spicy-software.com/GetThePicture/pictures/1.jpg
05-01 15:31:55.775: V/File:(2136): http://spicy-software.com/GetThePicture/pictures/2.jpg
05-01 15:31:55.775: V/File:(2136): http://spicy-software.com/GetThePicture/pictures/3.jpg
05-01 15:31:55.775: V/File:(2136): http://spicy-software.com/GetThePicture/pictures/4.jpg
05-01 15:31:55.775: V/File:(2136): http://spicy-software.com/GetThePicture/pictures/5.jpg
05-01 15:31:55.775: V/File:(2136): http://spicy-software.com/GetThePicture/pictures/6.jpg
05-01 15:31:55.775: V/File:(2136): http://spicy-software.com/GetThePicture/pictures/7.jpg
05-01 15:31:55.775: V/File:(2136): http://spicy-software.com/GetThePicture/pictures/8.jpg
05-01 15:31:55.775: V/FILE_1:(2136): http://www.spicy-software.com/GetThePicture/pictures/2.jpg
05-01 15:31:55.780: V/FTPTask(2136): FTP connection complete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that AsyncTask do not run in main thread and the code was too fast!
So it tried to load those images with imageloader BEFORE asynctask has finished...